# Mapping Virtual Memory to DRAM

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, shared-memory, ram

I'm trying to map U-Space allocated virtual memory (shm) to particular DIMM.
I succeed to retrieve the pfns using *get_user_pages_remote* for the start pointer to vmemory and then converting each *page* struct to pfn with *page_to_pfn*(btw these pfns are further used to create scatter-gather table for proprietary frame grabber device and do the job perfectly). However I don't find a way to recognize which physical DIMM (DRAM) each physical address (pfn) is originated from. Internet search yielded some DRAM address mapping schemes but all of them seam to handle inside-the-mmodule navigation i.e.:row, column, bank, channel & rank and all of the former are memory provider architecture dependent e.g.https://www.betriebssysteme.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Hillenbrand.pdf. On the other, side digging into SMBIOS Specification https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf, system resident DIMMs properties may be retrieved from /dev/mem (dmidecode -t memory), however I fail to link these two info sources together and finally map the pages.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Yoel.

Answer (score 5):

What you're really asking about is mapping a physical address to DRAM. In general there is no single answer and on a given system, there may be no specific address bit. You will need to know your memory geometry and how your memory controller is configured. On Linux, there's [decode-dimms](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/decode-dimms.1.html) which will query the DRAM chips themselves via an SPD protocol and that may tell you something about the memory geometry but not about the physical  to DRAM address mapping or its configuration. Your memory controller may scramble address bits to achieve more parallelism and to avoid bank thrashing. You have to get into the weeds.

Whereas the TLB hides the complexity of virtual to physical mapping, the DRAM memory controller hides the complexity of physical to DRAM mapping. (And you probably thought physical meant physical!) You need to learn more about physical to DRAM address mapping in general AND your memory controller and how the BIOS configures it in particular. [A good tutorial on physical to DRAM address mapping](https://www.anandtech.com/show/3851/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-sdram-memory-but-were-afraid-to-ask). [Another using a particular Sandy Bridge system.](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-physical-addresses-map-to-rows-and-banks.html) [A sample Micron data sheet](https://www.micron.com/-/media/documents/products/data%20sheet/dram/ddr3/4gb_ddr3_sdram.pdf). You'll need to look at the boot logic of your system as it will setup the memory controller. I don't know if there's a way to query the memory controller as to what its configuration is. The OS probably won't touch that configuration and will instead trust that the BIOS has done the right thing. It may be possible to determine these things empirically. RowHammer papers would be a good place to look for that.